# Binding multiple definitions to one "variable" in scheme?

Tags: variables, scheme, racket

I think I read somewhere that you could bind multiple definitions to a single name in scheme. I know I might be using the terminology incorrectly. By this I mean it is possible to do the following (which would be really handy to defining an operator)?

I believe I read something like this (I know this is not real syntax)

```
(let ()
define operator "+"
define operator "-"
define operator "*"
define operator "/"))
```

I want to test another variable against every operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking.  Do you want a single procedure that can handle different types of arguments?

```
(define (super-add arg1 arg2)
  (cond ((and (string? arg1) (string? arg2))
         (string-append arg1 arg2))
        ((and (number? arg1) (number? arg2))
         (+ arg1 arg2))
        (else
          (error "UNKNOWN TYPE -- SUPER-ADD"))))

(super-add "a" "b") => "ab"
(super-add 2 2) => 4
```

Are you interested in message passing?

```
(define (math-ops msg)  ;<---- returns a procedure depending on the msg
  (cond ((eq? msg 'add) +)
        ((eq? msg 'sub) -)
        ((eq? msg 'div) /)
        ((eq? msg 'multi) *)
        (else
          (error "UNKNOWN MSG -- math-ops"))))

((math-ops 'add) 2 2) => 4
((math-ops 'sub) 2 2) => 0
```

Also the proper syntax for a `let` binding:

```
(let (([symbol] [value])
      ([symbol] [value]))
   ([body]))

(let ((a 2)
      (b (* 3 3)))
   (+ a b))

 => 11
```

It will be very hard to help more than this without you clarifying what it is you are trying to do.

EDIT:  After your comment, I have a little bit better of an idea for what you're looking for.  There is not way to bind multiple values to the same name in the way that you mean.  You are looking for a predicate that will tell you whether the thing you are looking at is one of your operators.  From your comment it looked like you will be taking in a string, so that's what this is based on:

```
(define (operator? x)
    (or (string=? "+" x) (string=? "-" x) (string=? "*" x) (string=? "/" x)))
```

If you are taking in a single string then you will need to split it into smaller parts.  Racket has a built in procedure `regexp-split` that will do this for you.

```
(define str-lst (regexp-split #rx" +" [input str]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! let me make it a bit clearer.
The following are operands "+" "-" "*" "/" "(" ")"
I want to know if it is possible to simply bind them all to the name "operand"
So that if I am going through the list "3 + 4 - 6" it will recognize + and - as "operand." 
The goal of all this is to create a lexer that will give me token names in respect to the character in the list

Comment: @Ceelos What will your input be? A single string?  A list of strings? A scheme form?

Comment: Any string will do, But the actual project calls to read from a txt file which I will turn into a list. I know how to do that. 
(define file
(file->list "blah.txt"))

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to the `values` construct, which "delivers arguments to a continuation". It can be used to return multiple values from a function. For example,

```
(define (addsub x y)
  (values (+ x y) (- x y)))

(call-with-values
  (lambda () (addsub 33 12))
  (lambda (sum difference)
    (display "33 + 12 = ") (display sum) (newline)
    (display "33 - 12 = ") (display difference) (newline)))
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the `values`/`call-with-values` consruct.  Looking at Ceelos's comments and other questions though, it's probably not what they're looking for...